# android spinner to load json crashes

Tags: android

I am trying to fetch an array list using volley and display it in a spinner but my app crashes.
here is the main activity of the app

```
package com.example.shivadeeps.webservice;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Config;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import static java.lang.Character.getName;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Spinner spinner;
private ArrayList<String> trips;
private JSONArray result;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    trips= new ArrayList<String>();
    this.spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener((AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener) this);
    loadtrip();
}
public void loadtrip() {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(config.DATA_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    JSONObject j = null;
                    try {
                        j = new JSONObject(response);
                        result = j.getJSONArray(config.JSON_ARRAY);
                        getStudents(result);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
private void getStudents(JSONArray j){
    for(int i=0;i<j.length();i++){
        try {
            JSONObject json = j.getJSONObject(i);
            trips.add(json.getString(config.DATA_URL));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //Setting adapter to show the items in the spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,trips));
}
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {


}


}
```

XML code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/red"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.shivadeeps.webservice.MainActivity">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"

    android:layout_marginTop="100dp" ></Spinner>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_id"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:textColorHighlight="@android:color/primary_text_dark"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textSize="50dp"/>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

here is the logcat

> 01-10 11:29:25.226 12404-12404/com.example.shivadeeps.webservice
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                         Process: com.example.shivadeeps.webservice, PID: 12404
>                                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.shivadeeps.webservice/com.example.shivadeeps.webservice.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error
>   inflating class uses-permission
>                                                                                          at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3190)
>                                                                                          at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3300)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:211)
>                                                                                          at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1705)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946)
>                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                          at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
>                                                                                       Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13:
>   Error inflating class uses-permission
>                                                                                          at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
>                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
>                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
>                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
>                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
>                                                                                          at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
>                                                                                          at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143)
>                                                                                          at
>   com.example.shivadeeps.webservice.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
>                                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6575)
>                                                                                          at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)
>                                                                                          at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3143)
>                                                                                          at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3300) 
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:211) 
>                                                                                          at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1705) 
>                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946) 
>                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                          at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
>                                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "android.view.uses-permission" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.shivadeeps.webservice-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]]
>                                                                                          at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>                                                                                          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>                                                                                          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
>                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:578)
>                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:672)
>                                                                                          at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:65)
>                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:689)
>                                                                                          at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:748)
>                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813) 
>                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511) 
>                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
>                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
>                                                                                          at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
>                                                                                          at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143) 
>                                                                                          at
>   com.example.shivadeeps.webservice.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40) 
>                                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6575) 
>                                                                                          at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134) 
>                                                                                          at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3143) 
>                                                                                          at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3300) 
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:211) 
>                                                                                          at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1705) 
>                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946) 
>                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                          at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
>                                                                                         Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "android.view.uses-permission" on path: DexPathList[[dex file
>   "/data/data/com.example.shivadeeps.webservice/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-annotations-25.0.1_485a49a20ae18735d596aaa75d964eacffc01e9a-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.example.shivadeeps.webservice/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.example.shivadeeps.webservice/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.example.shivadeeps.webservice/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.example.shivadeeps.webservice/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.example.shivadeeps.webservice/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.example.shivadeeps.webservice/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.example.shivadeeps.webservice/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.example.shivadeeps.webservice/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.example.shivadeeps.webservice/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex",
>   dex file "/data/data/com.exa 01-10 11:29:25.231 2827-3392/?
>   W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity 1
>   com.example.shivadeeps.webservice/.MainActivity 01-10 11:29:25.241
>   2827-3392/? D/InputDispatcher: Focused application set to: xxxx 01-10
>   11:29:25.311 12691-12691/? D/Mms/MmsApp: [start]    initCountryIso
>   consume time = 103.6345 01-10 11:29:25.316 2827-3621/?
>   D/CountryDetector: The first listener is added 01-10 11:29:25.321
>   12691-12691/? D/Mms/MmsApp: [end]    initCountryIso consume time =
>   9.456961 01-10 11:29:25.416 2156-11978/? I/display: [PrimaryDisplay] [DYNAMIC_RECOMP] GLES_2_HWC by BW check 01-10 11:29:25.436
>   11562-11587/? I/Icing: Indexing
>   7491238841BD1692167B469A759AF4A2F8E28FA8 from
>   com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox 01-10 11:29:25.486 2827-3114/?
>   E/Watchdog: !@Sync 5200 [01-10 11:29:25.488] 01-10 11:29:25.531
>   12691-12691/? D/Mms/MmsConfig: [start]    MmsConfig.init() consume
>   time = 210.034154 01-10 11:29:25.546 2827-3392/? I/WindowManager:
>   Screenshot max retries 4 of Token{1ad8e437 ActivityRecord{3b472d36 u0
>   com.example.shivadeeps.webservice/.MainActivity t440 f}}
>   appWin=Window{2e5a232f u0 d0 Starting
>   com.example.shivadeeps.webservice} drawState=4 01-10 11:29:25.551
>   12691-12691/? D/EasySignUpManager_1.15.0305: isAuth is false 01-10
>   11:29:25.551 2827-12720/? E/android.os.Debug: ro.product_ship = true
>   01-10 11:29:25.551 2827-12720/? E/android.os.Debug: ro.debug_level =
>   0x4f4c 01-10 11:29:25.556 12691-12691/? D/Mms/MmsConfig:
>   getEasySignUpStatus sIsAuthEasySignUp=false,
>   TelephonyUtils.getSimState(0)= 1 01-10 11:29:25.556 2827-2852/?
>   D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : true 01-10
>   11:29:25.556 2827-2852/? D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor flags :
>   8519682 01-10 11:29:25.556 12691-12691/?
>   D/EasySignUpManager_1.15.0305: serviceId : 1, features : -1 01-10
>   11:29:25.556 12691-12691/? D/EasySignUpManager_1.15.0305: isAuth is
>   false 01-10 11:29:25.556 12691-12691/? D/EasySignUpManager_1.15.0305:
>   getServiceStatus : serviceId (1) is OFF 01-10 11:29:25.556
>   12691-12691/? D/Mms/MmsConfig: setFreeMessageEnabled,
>   getSupportedFeatures = -1 sIsAuthEasySignUp = false
>   sIsFreeMessageServiceStatus = false 01-10 11:29:25.556 12691-12691/?
>   D/Mms/MmsConfig: Load Resize quality : 80 01-10 11:29:25.561
>   12691-12691/? E/CscParser: mps_code.dat does not exist 01-10
>   11:29:25.566 12691-12691/? E/CscParser: customer_path
>   =/system/csc/customer.xml 01-10 11:29:25.566 12691-12691/? E/CscParser: fileName + /system/csc/customer.xml

Comment: error in your xml code. post it here

Comment: Problem is in `XML file`

Comment: Remove that permission form xml and add it in manifest...

Answer (score 1):

Please remove this from xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
```

and add them to Manifest file. This will solve your problem. 
**Permissions** are always added in Manifest file not in XML file.

Comment: @phoenixshiv Please post the logcat

Comment: @phoenixshiv After removing the above lines from xml and adding them in AndroidManifest.xml then also you are getting the same error?

Answer (score 0):

check this line in your code `spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener((AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener) this);`

Your setting click listener as "this", but your activity did not implement 
"AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener"

Your activity should implement AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener

Comment: spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this); gives me a error

Comment: Inflate exception is due to "no internet permission" in manifest as mentioned by Jagjit. Also until your activity implements "AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener", the line spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);  will throw error.

Comment: After adding permission, Modify your activity to public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener and add the required method

Comment: i did that app doesn't crash now but the spinner doesn't load the data

Comment: Debug and check what is the count of "trips" when you are setting adapter